# Add www. if it's not already in the string

Tags: php, regex

How do I make a string check by using regex if it contains `www.` in it. 
If string doesn't contain `www.`, then it should get added in front of the string. 
What php function can I use for this?

```
stackoverflow.com
```

should be:

```
www.stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: It could be as trivial as `substr($str, 0, 4) == 'www.'`...

Comment: If you plan on using that to always redirect to `www.`, you're better off using a `RewriteRule` with a `RewriteCond` in your `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$input = 'stackoverflow.com';
if (strpos($input, 'www.') !== 0) {
  $input = 'www.' . $input;
}
```

Comment: Simple and works, but it might run into trouble with less than basic URLs.

Comment: Careful when using this with protocol URLs, such as `https://example.com`

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure you would be better off using [parse_url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) rather than a regex for this:

```
<?php
$url = '//www.example.com/path?googleguy=googley';

// Prior to 5.4.7 this would show the path as "//www.example.com/path"
var_dump(parse_url($url));
?>

The above example will output:

array(3) {
  ["host"]=>
  string(15) "www.example.com"
  ["path"]=>
  string(5) "/path"
  ["query"]=>
  string(17) "googleguy=googley"
}
```

Once you have the snippets nicely split up for you, it is quite trivial to check the host.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "stackoverflow.com";

if(substr($str, 0, 4)!="www.")
{
  $str = "www.".$str;
}

echo $str;
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/3KDnwTQB)

Comment: he said **check by using regex** if it contains `www.` !

Comment: @angel **but that is a stupid requirement for this task**

Comment: that's possible :-D. I just answeared his question, that all ^^

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   if(!preg_match("/^w{3}[.]/", $string))
    {
       $string = "www.".$string;
    }
```

**EDIT :**
corrected

**input** : wwwut.example.com  **-->**  **output** : www.wwwut.example.com

Comment: This would fail for wwwut.example.com. Also if that would not be a problem it would still result in `int(0)`

Comment: yes, i forgot a point, sorry :-)

Comment: That dot doesn't do what you think it does ;-)

Comment: it will check if my string start with "www." and if it's not, that will add "www." before. but if the link start with http or https, or other , it will fail... But, my answear is correct for the question no ? maybe i do a mistake somewhere. it's possible :-D

Comment: Yes there are multiple mistakes in above. I suggest reviewing your code and updating your answer https://eval.in/156027